Dockerfile upgrade from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 8 which includes SQL Anywhere 17
I'm in the process of upgrading my API project to .NET 8, but I'm having issues including SQL Anywhere 17 drivers, which is an upgrade from SQL Anywhere 17 in my image. In .NET Core 3.1, it works fine, but not so much in .NET 8.
Unfortunately, I have no control over using SQL Anywhere as its a 3rd party system I'm integrating into.
Here is the original dockerfile for .NET Core 3.1:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=jaschweder/sybase /opt/sqlanywhere16 ./opt/sqlanywhere16
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
COPY ./Common/sqlanywhere-driver.template ./opt/sqlanywhere16/
RUN odbcinst -i -d -f /opt/sqlanywhere16/sqlanywhere-driver.template
ENV SQLANY16="/opt/sqlanywhere16"

ENV PATH="$SQLANY16/bin64:$SQLANY16/bin32:${PATH:-}"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$SQLANY16/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /out/ .
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Web.Api.dll" ]

So now, after lots of struggle, I need to manually download SQL Anywhere 17 and install it but even after all this, I can't get it to work.
Here is my .NET 8 docker file (it does look overwhelming but there are lots of validations to see where it fails):
# Stage 1: Building the .NET 8 application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /out

# Stage 2: Final runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
WORKDIR /app

# Install necessary tools and ODBC drivers
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    file \
    tar \
    gzip \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libtool \
    m4 \
    automake \
    autoconf \
    pkg-config

# Verify initial unixODBC installation
RUN echo "Verifying initial unixODBC installation:" && \
    which odbcinst && \
    odbcinst -j || { echo "odbcinst command failed"; exit 1; }

# Copy the unixODBC tarball to the container
COPY SQLAnywhereClient/unixODBC-2.3.11.tar.gz /tmp/unixODBC-2.3.11.tar.gz

# Manually install unixODBC
RUN cd /tmp && \
    tar -xzvf unixODBC-2.3.11.tar.gz && \
    cd unixODBC-2.3.11 && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install

# Verify manually installed unixODBC installation
RUN echo "Verifying manually installed unixODBC installation:" && \
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu && \
    which odbcinst && \
    odbcinst -j || { echo "odbcinst command failed"; exit 1; }

# Copy the SQL Anywhere 17 tarball to the container
COPY SQLAnywhereClient/sqla17_client_linux_x86x64.tar.gz /tmp/sqla17_client_linux_x86x64.tar.gz

# Inspect and extract the tarball
RUN cd /tmp && \
    echo "Checking file type of the tarball:" && \
    file sqla17_client_linux_x86x64.tar.gz && \
    echo "Attempting to extract the tarball using tar:" && \
    tar -xvf sqla17_client_linux_x86x64.tar.gz && \
    echo "Checking contents of /tmp after extraction:" && \
    ls -l /tmp && \
    echo "Checking contents of /tmp/client17011:" && \
    ls -l /tmp/client17011

# Make setup script executable and run it
RUN cd /tmp/client17011 && \
    echo "Making setup script executable:" && \
    chmod +x setup && \
    echo "Checking if setup script is executable:" && \
    ls -l setup && \
    echo "Running setup script:" && \
    ./setup -nogui -I_accept_the_license_agreement -silent || { echo "Setup script failed"; exit 1; }

# Ensure the required libraries are in the correct place
RUN ln -sf /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libdbodbc17.so /usr/lib/libdbodbc17.so && \
    ln -sf /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libodbc.so /usr/lib/libodbc.so.2 && \
    ln -sf /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libodbcinst.so /usr/lib/libodbcinst.so.2 && \
    ln -sf /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libodbcinst.so /usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.so.2 && \
    ln -sf /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libodbcinst.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2

# Set environment variables
ENV SQLANY17="/opt/sqlanywhere17"
ENV PATH="$SQLANY17/bin64:$SQLANY17/bin32:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:${PATH:-}"
ENV NODE_PATH="$SQLANY17/node:${NODE_PATH:-}"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$SQLANY17/lib32:$SQLANY17/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"

# Verify symbolic links and library paths
RUN echo "Verifying symbolic links and library paths:" && \
    ls -l /usr/lib/libodbcinst.so.2 && \
    ls -l /usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.so.2 && \
    ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2 && \
    ldconfig -p | grep odbcinst

# Create the ODBC driver template content directly
RUN echo "[SQL Anywhere 17]\nDescription=SQL Anywhere 17 ODBC Driver\nDriver=/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libdbodbc17.so\nSetup=/opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libdbodbc17.so\nUsageCount=1" > /asa.driver.template

# Configure ODBC driver
RUN . /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh && \
    echo "Verifying odbcinst installation:" && \
    which odbcinst && \
    odbcinst -i -d -f /asa.driver.template

# Verify installation steps
RUN echo "Step 1: Checking contents of /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64:" && \
    ls -l /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64 || echo "Directory /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64 does not exist"

RUN echo "Step 2: Checking if libodbc.so or libodbc.so.2 exists:" && \
    if [ -f /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libodbc.so ]; then echo "libodbc.so found"; else echo "libodbc.so not found"; fi && \
    if [ -f /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libodbc.so.2 ]; then echo "libodbc.so.2 found"; else echo "libodbc.so.2 not found"; exit 1; fi

RUN echo "Step 3: Checking if libdbodbc17.so exists:" && \
    if [ -f /opt/sqlanywhere17/lib64/libdbodbc17.so]; then echo "libdbodbc17.so found"; else echo "libdbodbc17.so not found"; exit 1; fi

RUN echo "Step 4: Checking odbcinst installation:" && \
    which odbcinst && \
    odbcinst -j

RUN echo "Step 5: Checking installed drivers:" && \
    odbcinst -q -d

RUN echo "Step 6: Checking configured data sources:" && \
    odbcinst -q -s

COPY --from=build /out/ .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.Api.dll"]

This is the error I get and can't seem to get away from it even when I install unixODBC

Verifying initial unixODBC installation:
odbcinst command failed

I had these steps in but then downloaded the files
# Manually download and install SQL Anywhere
RUN wget https://www.sqlanywhere.info/download/2022/sqla17_client_linux_x86x64.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzvf sqla17_client_linux_x86x64.tar.gz && \
    cd sqla17_client_linux_x86x64 && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install

# Manually download and install unixODBC
RUN wget http://www.unixodbc.org/unixODBC-2.3.11.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzvf unixODBC-2.3.11.tar.gz && \
    cd unixODBC-2.3.11 && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install


I have no experience about SQL Anywhere.
From this line:
/asa.driver.template

I assume that you are working with Sybase aka SAP.
If we turn to the user manual the vendor promises to work in .NET 6. In my opinion, everything ind indicates that he is not at all interested in your problems and the relevance of his drivers. Moreover, they use ODBC for Linux, they have obvious problems and they need to make a serious effort to release a modern driver.
This is sad.
I see several solutions:

I'm sorry if you've already tried this option, I don't know your path. But it might be worth considering solutions from the open-source camp, for example: https://github.com/DataAction/AdoNetCore.AseClient.  Although, the project has not received updates for several years, it may be working, you can fork it and simply update the dependencies.

You can try to use downgrade your project to .NET 6 and wait for vendor's solution. At least, this is better to use .NET 3.1.

You can add strace/ltrace package to you Docker container. This utility is tracer for processes and you can understand what is happening at the system call level and this may give you a clue. You need to it inside a container. Typical usage: strace -p <ProcessID>

Another option is to separate the project into a database level and a web server level with other functionality, putting these levels in different containers that communicate with each other through, for example, a unix pipes. Of course, this option is a little bit crazy, but it also exists as an alternative.


